# UITableView and UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am new in iPhone developing. I have one UITableView with three Section and each Section has  three rows. And I have one UISegmentedControl with three index.the tableview is hidden initially .when I select any index of segmentIndex then its display the tableview with three section.
     But my question is that when I select index of segmented control then its display the tableView with only one section and other two section is hide in the tableView.How to do it please answer
     Here is my code

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"


@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize tblView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    //Customize tableview
    tblView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    firstName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Parth",@"Bhadresh",@"Marshal", nil];
    middleName = [NSArray      arrayWithObjects:@"Dipakbhai",@"Dineshbhai",@"Mansukhbhai",nil];
    lastName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Patel",@"Laiya",@"Kaneria", nil];
    tblView.delegate = self;
    tblView.dataSource = self;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    sgmtControl.frame = CGRectMake(17, 180, 285, 44);    
    tblView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 364);
    tblView.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:tblView];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            return 3;
            break;
        case 1:
            return 3;
            break;
        case 2:
            return 3;
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            return @"FirstName";
            break;
        case 1:
            return @"MiddleName";
            break;
        case 2:
            return @"LastName";
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *myIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    }

    switch (indexPath.section)
    {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text =[firstName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = [middleName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = [lastName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
-(IBAction)changeSegement:(id)sender
{
    if(sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        tblView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else if (sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        tblView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else if (sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
    {
        tblView.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: reload the table in every segment click

Comment: reloed table in every segment display all of three section in my tableview. But I want to display only one section and other two section is hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this,

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    switch (sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            return [firstName count];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [middleName count];
            break;
        case 2:
            return [lastName count];
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
    switch (sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            return @"FirstName";
            break;
        case 1:
            return @"MiddleName";
            break;
        case 2:
            return @"LastName";
            break;
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *myIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    }

    switch (sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text =[firstName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = [middleName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = [lastName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
-(IBAction)changeSegement:(id)sender
{
    if(sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        tblView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else if (sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        tblView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else if (sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
    {
        tblView.hidden = NO;
    }
    [tblView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little modification in Mountain Lion's code to make it more generic and to remove switches

```
@synthesize currentArray;
.
.
.
.

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      .
      .
      .
      //ALLOCATE currentArray
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return currentArray.count;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
    switch (sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            return @"FirstName";
            break;
        case 1:
            return @"MiddleName";
            break;
        case 2:
            return @"LastName";
            break;
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *myIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    }

   cell.textLabel.text =[currentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return cell;
}
-(IBAction)changeSegement:(id)sender
{
    if(sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        currentArray = firstName;
    }
    else if (sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        currentArray = middleName;
    }
    else if (sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
    {
        currentArray = lastName;
    }
    tblView.hidden = NO;
    [tblView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe i understand what you are trying to do, you want to display different table view cells depending on which of the button segments is selected.

You need to have your cellForRowAtIndexPath check which segment is selected and return the correct set of cells.

When the user changes the segmented button, have changeSegment: store the selected segment in an instance variable. Then have it call [self reloadData];

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"


@interface DetailViewController ()
{
    NSArray *names;
    NSInteger segIndex;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *names;
@property (nonatomic) segIndex;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize tblView;
@synthesize names;
@synthesize segIndex;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    //Customize tableview
    tblView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    self.names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Parth",@"Bhadresh",@"Marshal", nil],
                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dipakbhai",@"Dineshbhai",@"Mansukhbhai",nil],
                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Patel",@"Laiya",@"Kaneria", nil],
                  nil];
    tblView.delegate = self;
    tblView.dataSource = self;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    sgmtControl.frame = CGRectMake(17, 180, 285, 44);
    tblView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 364);
    tblView.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:tblView];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.names count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self.names objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            return @"FirstName";
        case 1:
            return @"MiddleName";
        case 2:
            return @"LastName";
    }
    return nil;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *myIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text =[[self.names objectAtIndex:self.segIndex] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
-(IBAction)changeSegement:(id)sender
{
    self.segIndex = sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [self reloadData];
}
```

Comment: its little work first time button segment is selected its display the one section and other is hidden but second time its display the two section and third time select the button segment display tableview with three section I want to every time button segment is selected its display only one section and other two are hidden

Comment: @parthpatel You're welcome.  If this is the code you used in your program, please mark this response as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
switch (sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
{
    case 0:
        return 3;
        break;
    case 1:
        return 3;
        break;
    case 2:
        return 3;
        break;
}
return 0;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
switch (sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
{
    case 0:
        return @"FirstName";
        break;
    case 1:
        return @"MiddleName";
        break;
    case 2:
        return @"LastName";
        break;
   }
 }

  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *myIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];
}

switch (sgmtControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
{
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text =[firstName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel.text = [middleName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel.text = [lastName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        break;
}
return cell;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //You may get hint from my code
   //UISegmentedControl with TableView using Objective C

  //complete working code

@interface TabTwoScheduleViewController () <UITableViewDelegate ,       UITableViewDataSource>
{
CGRect rect;
NSArray *list;
NSArray *list1;
NSArray *list2;
NSArray *list3;
NSArray *list4;
UITableView *segmentTableView;
}
@end

@implementation TabTwoScheduleViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

 rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];

UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, rect.size.width-20, rect.size.height/10-23)];
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height * 2);
scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"ONLINE", @"CLASSROOM", @"WEBCASTING", nil];
list = [NSArray     arrayWithObjects:@"list.1",@"list.2",@"list.3",@"list.4",@"list.5", nil];
list1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"list1.1",@"list1.2",@"list1.3",@"list1.4",@"list1.5", nil];
list2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"list2.1",@"list2.2",@"list2.3",@"list2.4",@"list2.5", nil];
list3 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"list3.1",@"list3.2",@"list3.3",@"list3.4",@"list3.5", nil];
list4 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"list4.1",@"list4.2",@"list4.3",@"list4.4",@"list4.5", nil];

// segmentedControl is declared as property
self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]     initWithItems:itemArray];
self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width-20, 50);
self.segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle =UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
[self.segmentedControl addTarget:self  action:@selector(MySegmentControlAction:) forControlEvents:     UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
[scroll addSubview:self.segmentedControl];
[self.view addSubview:scroll];

//ADDING TABLEVIEW OVER VIEW(I added this view to get leading and trailing space for tableViewCell)

 UIView *vw = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];
   vw.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:vw];

    //TABLE VIEW
segmentTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, rect.size.width-20, rect.size.height-230)   style:UITableViewStylePlain];
segmentTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

segmentTableView.delegate = self;
segmentTableView.dataSource = self;

[vw addSubview:segmentTableView];
    }

// number of sections for tableView
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)theTableView
{
NSInteger a=0;
switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
{
    case 0:
        a=list.count;
    break;

case 1:
    a=list1.count;
    break;

 case 2:
    a=list1.count;
    break;

   default:
    a=list1.count;
    break;
}
    return a;
 }
 // number of row in the section
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView   numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 1;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier =    @"ScheduleCustomTableViewCell";

//ScheduleCustomTableViewCell is name of custom TabelViewCell
ScheduleCustomTableViewCell *cell =(ScheduleCustomTableViewCell *)   [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]   loadNibNamed:@"ScheduleCustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

// conditions to get different values on label
if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
{
cell.labelAddress1.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
cell.labelAddress2.text = [list1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
}
else if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
{
cell.labelAddress1.text = [list1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
cell.labelAddress2.text = [list2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
}
else
{
cell.labelAddress1.text = [list2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
cell.labelAddress2.text = [list3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
}
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

return cell ;
 }
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView* )tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath* )indexPath
{
return 130;
}
// Header is given to get spacing between TableViewCells
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
return 10;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
 UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
 return headerView;
 }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
```

}

```
- (void)MySegmentControlAction:(UISegmentedControl *)segment
{
[segmentTableView reloadData];
}

 @end
```